# Flutter Firestore Deleted Document Greyed Out And Resurrected Unwantedly

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to delete a document in Firestore using the

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('Users')
    .document('${user.uid}')
    .collection('Pets')
    .document('${dogNameList[index]}')
    .delete()
```

When this happens, I see the Firestore console and the correct document to be deleted is greyed out, however, it is not deleted:

[image: Greyed Out Document]

Next, when I create a new pet in this case, for some reason, if this pet has the same name 'Turbo' as the greyed out document name on the console, it inherently gets all the data which the old supposedly deleted 'Turbo' document has... This means that the document is not really being deleted but is rather going into some hibernation state or something like that... I need to know how I can permanently delete this document programmatically!

Thanks a lot and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Does that document have any sub-collections? `delete` is not recursive.

Comment: Yes, the document has a sub collection

Comment: You need to delete any child documents as well to fully delete it.

Comment: So, if i wanted to delete a collection i would i need to delete every single document inside it on my own. Or i can just call the delete function

Comment: Is there any easy way to delete a document as well as all the data and collections inside it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you see an document id in italics, the only thing that means is that the document doesn't exist, but it has nested subcollections that are still present. If you click the document ID, you should be able to see those subcollections.  This is why the document ID is still visible - to let you navigate to those subcollections in the console.

If you want to delete those subcollections as well, you will need to write code to delete all their documents.

See also: [Delete a Document with all Subcollections and Nested Subcollections in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286764/delete-a-document-with-all-subcollections-and-nested-subcollections-in-firestore)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it!!

Comment: The linked question has its code in some other language! Would you mind linking me to a question with the answer written in Dart?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately.  I strongly urge you to try to solve the problem yourself and post the code that doesn't work the way you expect.  Otherwise, it will get closed as "off topic" for needing focus.

Comment: Thanks, Doug! I appreciate your help!