# How to find Firestore collections which don't have parent documents?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm trying to clean up my Google Cloud Firestore database, and I have some subcollections with no parent doc (the parent was deleted). How can I find all of those, using the Firebase Admin SDK, so I can delete them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will end up writing a lot of code for this.  I'm going to link to nodejs APIs.

For each collection where there *could* be missing documents, you will need to need to query that collection with [listDocuments()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#listDocuments).  That will return a list of all documents in the collection, including the missing documents that have subcollections.  You will then need to iterate the [DocumentReferences](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html) returned in that list, and call [get()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#get) on every one of them.  The returned [DocumentSnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html) will then tell you if it exists or not using its `exists` property.

After you have all the DocumentReference objects referring to missing documents, you can then follow the instructions in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286764/delete-a-document-with-all-subcollections-and-nested-subcollections-in-firestore) that describes how to delete all nested subcollections under that DocumentReference, go straight to the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections).

Comment: Thanks -- I'll try this. Doesn't sound too bad actually. I didn't realize that `listDocuments` would return "missing" docs; that's good. I already have the deep document/collection deleter from https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/361.