# Deleting document from Firestore with Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make this Cloud Function to work. I would like to delete a document from Firestore that has as name the previous date of function execution. This function is supposed to be executed every night at 2am, but for some reason it is not working. Here is my code:

```
exports.deleteYesterday = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("0 02 * * *")
    .onRun(async (context) => {
        var yesterday = new Date();
        var dd = String(yesterday.getDate() - 1).padStart(2, "0");
        var mm = String(yesterday.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0"); 
        var yyyy = yesterday.getFullYear();

        const dateString = (yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd).toString();

        let ref = admin.firestore().collection("citas").doc(dateString);
        return ref.delete();
    });
```

When logging dateString value I get the correct date format I need:
[dateString](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yonva.png)

This is how the database looks like:
[documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOte2.png)

Thanks!!

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Please log all the values of the variables you're using here, and confirm that they are what you expect.  We can't see into the data in your database, nor the values of these string, in order to verify this program should do what you want.  You can edit the question with your debugging information using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database screenshot shows that there is no document called "citas/2020-12-02".  It was likely already deleted.  You can tell because the name of the document is in italics.  That italics means that there is no document, but there are nested subcollections organized under it.  Those subcollections will not be deleted when you delete the parent document.  You will have to write some code to delete all of the documents in the subcollections if you want it to disappear.

See also:

- [Delete a Document with all Subcollections and Nested Subcollections in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286764/delete-a-document-with-all-subcollections-and-nested-subcollections-in-firestore)